# can logstash container logs be configured using logstash.yml file to a specific path?

Tags: docker, logging, logstash

In normal logstash we have a config folder inside we will configure the logs and other stuff related to the logstash configuration which include logstash.yml,log4j2.properties,jvm.options and startup.options. Is this possible to do inside the container also so that the logs will be written in a file other than giving a stdout?

Answer (score 1):

Under Docker, Logstash logs go to standard output by default. To change this behaviour, use any of the techniques above to replace the file at /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties.